# Can a function be a solution of an ODE even though it solves it for just one value of the domain?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definition

According to some material I was reading, it says that a function $f$ with domain in an interval $I$ is a solution of a differential equation in the interval $I$ if $f$ satisfies that differential equation in the interval I. For instance, does it mean that $y=ax^n$, where $n>1$ is an integer and $a\neq0$ is a constant, is a solution for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ in the interval of $x=0$? I found this answer and I suspect it may be related to my question. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311041/1174565

Regarding the answer in the link, I was thinking that it seems like $I$ in this case doesn't meet the conditions (I think $I$ is connected, but not open and degenerate instead, which in turns makes the function non-differentiable because it just goes from $x=0$ to $y=0$ and is not defined for any other values), thus saying $y=ax^n$ is a solution for the ODE in $I$ is vacuously true.

I would appreciate it if you let me know any misconception I may have regarding this issue and the definitions.

Comment: The concept, "solution on the interval $[0,0] = \{0\}$" is included in the definition.  However, that is a useless concept.  Solution on an interval of positive length is the interesting case.  Consequently: when we ask for a solution of a DE, we would not be satisfied to get an answer that solves it only at one point.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you. What do you mean with "is included in the definition"? Does it mean that my last conclusion is not _vacuously_ true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a degenerate interval if you consider it an interval at all. In the context of differential equations, and really anywhere involving derivatives, we want to think about *open* intervals, since the derivative is all about the behavior of a function *in a neighborhood* of a given point. We have to have some amount of definition on either side of the given point in order to have a derivative.

As soon as we require the ODE to hold on an open neighborhood, then $y = ax^n$ with $a \neq 0$ no longer satisfies $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ away from the point $x=0$.